# Use an Android tablet for drawing on PC while seeing only a zoomed in portion of the entire screen

Tags: tablet, windows, input-methods, drawing

I'm looking for a way to utilize my 10" Samsung tablet as a drawing display tablet for use with arbitrary Windows 10 apps (like Photoshop, any pixel art tools, basically without hard limitations) with support for only seeing a zoomed in fragment of the screen, while the screen still shows everything without cropping/reducing the resolution only to what the tablet can show.

Because my desktop monitor's resolution is 3840x2160px at 48" and the tablet is 1920x1200px at 10", I would like to be able to match up the scale and visible region on the tablet to that on the monitor, with a pinch-to-zoom gesture on the fly, so I can only work on a part of the screen at a time. Seeing the contents of the entire monitor on the tablet or having to lower monitor resolution to match the tablet's is not very usable for drawing. With Teamviewer, I can't figure out how to use it to draw at all - it translates all touches into drag motions for Photoshop, and it only shows the entire visible screen, without the ability to zoom in on a small part.

I don't have any special touch pens for the Samsung tablet, and it this model does not have any special pen support. So I guess I'm looking to translate all touch as mouse clicks to PC.

Is there a modern piece of software for Windows 10 and/or an Android app to make this work?

Comment: I've seen similar questions but they're either severely outdated, like from 2013 and the app isn't there anymore or doesn't support modern Android versions, or extremely slow or doesn't work for drawing (like Teamviewer). Also, I can't tell if this is an appropriate question of if I should try Softwarerecs.SE